# SQL Change named AS colum based on returned values

Tags: sql, if-statement

Looking to use different column values on return after a join, if a value is NOT NULL.

Seems hard to explain but if I have a select statement that names a colum with AS, then Join another valuem and if that is NOT NULL use that new column value in place of the first.

```
SELECT a.value1 AS value 
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id   (assume this is one to one)
```

What I want is table2 has a column value2, and if that is NOT NULL then make b.value2 AS value

In code would be

```
    if (b.value) {
       $value = b.value2;
    } else {
       $value = a.value1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(t2.value2, a.value1) AS value
FROM table a LEFT JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id ;
```

Comment: I am amazed at how much I don't know still, and how much is easily solved but hard to find via search.  Thank You.

Comment: @RadiumChris . . . That is why it is really helpful to have Q&A site where people at different levels can ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN b.value2 IS NOT NULL THEN b.value2
      ELSE a.value1
    END
   AS value
FROM table a 
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
```